Getting a WebPartPageUserException trying to activate a feature (via Powershell) that installs a CEWP on a Wiki page
SP 2016. I have a web-scoped feature that

deploys an HTML page to the Site Assets library via a module
has feature activation code that:
creates a new Wiki page in the Site Pages library
inserts a Content Editor Web Part into the new Wiki page
sets the "Content Link" property of the CEWP to the URL of the HTML file in the Site Assets library

This works like a charm if you go to the site features page and click the Activate button in a browser, but it is failing if I try to activate the feature via Powershell Enable-SPFeature.
Specifically, the part that is failing is the insertion of the CEWP:
SPFile page = web.GetFile(urlToNewWikiPage);
if (page.Exists)
{
    SPList siteAssets = web.Lists["Site Assets"];

    ContentEditorWebPart cewp = new ContentEditorWebPart();
    cewp.ChromeType = PartChromeType.None;
    cewp.ContentLink = $"{siteAssets.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl}/my-subfolder/my-page.html";

    WikiEditPage.InsertWebPartIntoWikiPage(page, cewp, 0);
}

The exception I catch is as follows
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPageUserException

This page has encountered a critical error. Contact your system administrator if this problem persists.

 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SafeControls.IsSafeControl(Boolean isAppWeb, Type type, String& unsafeErrorMessage, Boolean blockPropertyTraversal, Boolean containsTraversalChars)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.TypeCache.CheckIfSafeControl(Type type, Boolean isAppWeb)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.TypeCache.get_Item(Type type, Boolean isAppWeb, Boolean disableSafeControlsCheck)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.WriteXmlGlobal(Boolean disableSafeControlsCheck)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BinaryWebPartSerializer.Serialize(SerializationMode mode, BinaryWebPartSerializerFlag binaryWebPartSerializerFlags, SPSerializationBinderBase serializationBinder, BinaryWebPartSerializerWriter writer)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.AddWebPartToStore(WebPart webPart, Int32 viewId, String viewGuid)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.AddWebPartInternal(SPSupersetWebPart superset, Boolean throwIfLocked)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WikiEditPage.InsertWebPartIntoWikiPage(SPFile wikiFile, WebPart webpart, Int32 position)  

Nearby my entries in the ULS logs where I catch the exception (same correlation ID) there are
Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x800707dc
<nativehr>0x800707dc</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: <nativehr>0x800707dc</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>, StackTrace:   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.ThrowIfCantModifyZone(String zoneID, Boolean throwIfLocked)

[my caught exception here]

Cannot complete this action.  Please try again.<nativehr>0x80004005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

The Powershell script is being run by a service account that has Site Collection Admin rights on the site collection / subsite where I'm trying to activate the feature.
Even so, just in case it might help, I wrapped all that code inside an SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges delegate, and it still throws the same errors when the feature is activated by Powershell (but still works when activated from a browser).
Any ideas as to what's going on here, and why it would work if I do it manually from a browser, but doesn't work from Powershell?
